# JSON Response values in IOS

Tags: json

Please let me know the code for how to parse the JSON response in a tabelview cell

http://ccwm.co/demo/meetmatchandgo/mmg/api/popularEvents

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You should be ashamed of yourself. Write your code, if it doesn't work, ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you are searching for:

```
NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&localError];

    if (localError != nil) {
        *error = localError;
        return nil;
    }
```

Take a look at [this post](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/) for more info with table views and everything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like voting Questions down, but I completely agree with gnasher729's comments.

There is a *huge* number of examples out there explaining how to do this, and it's not for StackOverflow readers to write your code for you.

I would strongly recommend buying a copy of the "iOS Apprentice" series to teach you how to do this, or have a read of this walkthrough.

[Load JSON data in Xcode](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page6.htm)

Come back to StackOverflow when you've got a basic understanding and *then* have specific problems.